# ssh-keygen is not generating OPENSSH key, not RSA key

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-keygen

I generated a new keypair but it is generating OPENSSH key only. None of the below command generates RSA key.

`ssh-keygen`
`ssh-keygen -t rsa`

This just started happening this week. All keys I have generated earlier are RSA keys.

I do not want pem file or Any help?

Answer (score 0):

New keys with OpenSSH private key format can be converted using ssh-keygen utility to the old PEM format.

```
ssh-keygen -p -m PEM -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```